# Here Map View Getting Overlay on the Top of App Bar In flutter

Tags: flutter, heremaps

I have Used a Here Map SDK for the Map Feature in my app instead of Google Map,
I have tried to fit the map inside the body of the scaffold, but Map View Getting Over App bar out Side and seems positioned outside of the body.

I have shared the ref screenshot and Code, please suggest any solution.
Thanks

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    logger.i('Build Function Executed');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Location'),
        ),
        body: Expanded(
          child: HereMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          ),
        ));
  }
```

[ScreenShot from Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNusq.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    logger.i('Build Function Executed');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Location'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
         child: Expanded(
          child: HereMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          ),
        )));
  }
```

add `SafeArea` widget

Comment: Thanks for the reply,It's Not Working getting same issue like Mentioned ScreenShot